# Security, Hacking, Cryptography Reading?

Tags: cryptography, steganography

I'm very interested in learning about cryptography, steganography, and similar practices.

What books, resources, would you guys recommend in this area?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771069/good-resources-on-security-hacking-etc

Comment: Not sure - cryptography / steganography isn't strictly about hacking and finding exploits in programs as opposed to finding hidden messages in otherwise uninteresting sources, i.e. hiding messages in jpegs, as opposed to locating and performing a sql injection.

Comment: Hello - quick comment to say that since you asked your question, we now have a [crypto.stackexchange.com](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) site especially for Q&A on cryptography.

Comment: The first half of the book uses only psuedo code, and is an encyclopedia of usefull stuff from the field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seminal crypto book
http://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I see the book is based on C. As a primarily Java developer (plus many dynamic langs) - how heavy is the reliance on C knowlegde. Although I really should know C by now anyway to be honest!

Comment: If you want to learn about crypto you first need the math. (this book covers this adequately).
Second you need the protocols (no communications but security).

No amount of math and crypto will work if you screw up the protocol.

There isn't a lot of C code in the book and you won't be at a disadvantage.

Comment: @lucas1000001 The examples are in C but the key thing with the book is learning the ideas, theories and algorithms - once you have that it's easily transferable to Java. Great book - about the best intro to security for coders out there

Answer (score 4):

This  book is very nice and gives you a general idea about cryptography and as far as I remember some it gives also some information about steganography (from the ancient times): 
[The Code Book: The Science of Secrecy from Ancient Egypt to Quantum Cryptography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0385495323) although not an academic book.

For steganography you could check also the following two: [Disappearing Cryptography, Third Edition: Information Hiding: Steganography & Watermarking](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123744792)  or [Digital Watermarking and Steganography: Fundamentals and Techniques](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1420047574). As you are a Java developer you may also want to take a look at the [Digital Invisible Ink Toolkit](http://diit.sourceforge.net/).

If you want to go deep into Cryptography (for example RSA algorithm) you should read math books about number theory, abstract algebra (for an introduction to these you can check this: [A Primer on Algebra and Number Theory for Computer Scientists](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall02/G22.3033-010/notes.pdf) (it's a pdf file)). Or if you want to go much deeper you should read about elliptic curve cryptography.

About hacking you may want to take a look at this one: Hacking: [The Art of Exploitation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271441).

This book [The Art of Deception: Controlling the Human Element of Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/076454280X) is also  nice to read in order to learn social engineering techniques.

Answer (score 2):

For learning hacking, i would suggest The art of Exploitation by John Ericson, Grey Hat hacking, Network Security and cryptography by William Stalling and even better playing online wargames (security challanges).
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Schneier book already mentioned, I recommend [Beginning Cryptography With Java](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Cryptography-with-Java.productCd-0764596330.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, in order to integrate your books with a different media, this online course: https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto
It's very well done, it offers both theoretical and practical sessions.

Answer (score 0):

The [Coursera crypto](https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto) course is a good introduction to cryptography.  As far as practical resources go I would suggest:

- [Over the wire](http://www.overthewire.org/wargames/) - practical security challenges from basic configuration issues to exploit dev.
- [SmashTheStack](http://smashthestack.org/) - lots more practical security challenges.
- [Corelan tutorials](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/category/security/exploit-writing-tutorials/) - tutorials on exploit development
- [DEF CON](http://www.defcon.org/html/links/book-list.html) - Defcon is a famous security conference that also has a reasonable reading list and a lot of videos from their conferences.

In my development experience I have found it useful to have a go at some of these things to really improve my secure software development.  There are also [capture the flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capture_the_flag#Computer_security) events that are events designed to educate and test security knowledge and deep knowledge of systems.  Some of them include:

- [DEF CON](http://www.defcon.org) - probably the biggest and toughest of them all
- [Ghost in the Shellcode](http://ghostintheshellcode.com/) - hosted at Shmoocon
- [Plaid CTF](http://www.plaidctf.com/) - run by team from Carnegie Mellon University
- [CSAW](https://csawctf.poly.edu/) - run by NYU Poly