# What is a good list of resources to learn system security?

Tags: security, system

I'm interested in learning system security. I'm thinking of installing Damn Vulnerable Linux on one of my spare machines to test on. Anyone have any recommendations, reads, methods or tutorials?

Comment: Another resource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771069/good-resources-on-security-hacking-etc

Comment: Check out the [Security Stack Exchange site](http://security.stackexchange.com/). They have several [resource lists](http://security.stackexchange.com/tags/education) already, e.g. [Resources to learn about security](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/266/414), [Courses on “Secure Software Development”](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/1/414), [Books about Penetration Testing](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/2013/414).

Comment: @Gilles HAHA! You're kidding?! There is a Sercurity stack exchange? Wow. I have just been learned.

Comment: This is not a C or C++ question. I have therefore removed those tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days exploiting C/C++  and operating systems is **not easy**.   You are starting with a massive topic.  The only more complex security topic would be cryptography.   With anything you need to start small and then work your way up.  You should start with web application security.  You should be learning about the most common vulnerabilities such as XSS and SQL Injection,  [Google Gruyre](http://google-gruyere.appspot.com/) is a good resource.

If you are very skilled then you might be able to get though old paper [smashing the stack for fun and profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html).  A good book for learning how to attack modern c/c++ applications is Exploiting Software: How to break code. [image]

Comment: Hah! Noted sir, thanks for the input. If everyone was detered by the daunting, we wouldn't have much in the ways of innovation.

Comment: I own the book, it's awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that information security is too broad a topic, and list of interesting problems are too many to enumerate. Since you say about Damn vulnerable linux, I assume that you are confining this to operating system.

If so, some interesting topics would be - i) Buffer Overflow attacks - Stack smashing attacks, Integer overflow and Heap smashing attacks, etc. and ii) TOCTOU attacks. http://insecure.org/ is a good resource and has bunch of tutorials on them. Also, the vulnerabilities, and some attack payload can be found in vulnerability reporting DB such as secunia.org and cert.org. Also, it might be worth to study about network exploits - on how deep-packet inspection can detect simple worms. Advanced topics might include polymorphic and self-modifying worms. Firewalls can be an eventual topic.

Comment: Tahnk for the input, I will look into all that :)